# How to retrieve the result of a php gmail api send mail and modify the label of the message

Tags: php, gmail-api

I'm sending small e-mail campaigns through my php site by using the gmail api. 
I would like to know how to return of the the message was sent successfully or not and catch also the error in a variable. (for example if the email address format is not correct or a problem with gmail connection etc)

So I would like to get two variable: 
$sent_success = 0 or 1 depending on the return.
$error_msg="the error message catched from gmail api"

On top of that after send the message I would like to apply a label to it so it's removed from the sent items in gmail.

Sending the message causes no problem.

Here's my code snippet:

```
    $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

    $fromemail = "someemail@mail.com";
    $strRawMessage = "From: fromname <$fromemail> \r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "To: ".$CONTACTS_FNAME." ".$CONTACTS_LNAME." <$RECIPIENT>\r\n";    
$strRawMessage .= 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($EMAILSUBJECT) . "?=\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . "\r\n\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "$EMAILBODY\r\n";
    $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    $msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
    $msg->setRaw($mime);
    $service->users_messages->send("me", $msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it myself using try and catch method:

```
try {
                SEND_MAIL($row['CONTACTS_EMAIL'],$EMAILSUBJECT,$EMAILBODY,$row['CONTACTS_FNAME'],$row['CONTACTS_LNAME']);

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $err = $e->getMessage();
            }
```